# URL is redirecting to "www.example.com/undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a three level dependent drop-down(country-state-city) using jquery, AJAX and JSON. To redirect the user to a page after he selected city ([www.example.com/city](http://www.example.com/city), the city is numeric value here) I used the following code, HTML

```
<select name="city" id="city" class="form-control input-lg" onchange="onfuct()">
 <option value="">Select City</option>
</select>
```

The javascript is here

```
var value_1 = document.getElementByID('city').value;

function onfuct () {
   window.location.replace("www.example.com"/+value_1);
}
```

Can somebody help me out it is redirecting to "www.example.com/undefined"

Comment: Can you share what your select options looks lik? Most likely you are not setting values right.

Comment: Getting `undefined` from `"url"+/value_1` so clearly `value_1` is `undefined` so clearly `var value_1 =` isn't how you "get  value from select" - so: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+get+value+from+select

Comment: @DipenShah https://www.webslesson.info/2017/05/json-dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-and-ajax.html  i copied it from here.

Comment: Did you check Adam's answer?

Comment: @DipenShah yes not working

Answer (score 1):

`value` does not exist on `<select>`, you need to do a bit more work to obtain the selected value. Also, JavaScript is case-sensitive; `getElementByID` is NOT `getElementById`

```js
// Get the element from DOM
const city = document.getElementById('city');

/*
  Move event listeners to JavaScript like

  city.addEventListener('onchange', onfuct)

*/

function onfuct() {
  // city.options returns the option elements
  let selectedCity = city.options[city.selectedIndex].value;

  console.log("www.example.com/" + selectedCity);
}
```

```html
<select name="city" id="city" class="form-control input-lg" onchange="onfuct()">
  <option value="stockholm">Stockholm</option>
  <option value="new-york">New York</option>
  <option value="oslo">Oslo</option>
</select>
```